# xpath for background-image url

Tags: html, css, xpath

I'm trying to get a background image url using xpath .

my xpath expression so far:

```
//div[@class='Header']/div[@class='Header-jpeg']
```

which points to the `div` that has the `background-image` but from there no idea how to get the img url, probably something in `@style` but no luck so far.

Css of that div:

```
div.Header-jpeg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 874px;
    height: 94px;
    background-image: url('images/Header.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

and a real example ca be found here:
http://www.landenkompas.nl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='Header']/div[@class='Header-jpeg']/@style, 'background-image: url('), ')')
```

However, be warned that if you're using Java XPath it will only get the first element it finds. If you have multiple, you'll need to find another way to aggregate all the values.

Comment: That's the right answer as far as I remember, it might get tricky though sometimes as some sites use something slightly different like `"` vs `i` or an extra space etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using selenium, you need to get a *value of the CSS property*.

In Java:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Header']/div[@class='Header-jpeg']"));
element.getCssValue("background-image");
```

In Python:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Header']/div[@class='Header-jpeg']")
element.value_of_css_property("background-image")
```